# jquery setting adaptive top-margins to images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, responsive-design, margin

thi is my code :

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="one">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <img>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know the height of the divs and images and I want to set a top-margin relative to div and img height only if img is less tall than the div and only in div class="one".

this is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".one").each(function(){
    var wrapH = $(".one").outerHeight();
    var imgH = $("img").outerHeight();
    var padTop = (wrapH-(imgH))/2;
      if (padTop>0){
        $("img").css("margin-top", padTop + "px");
      }
  });
});
```

this changes margins off all images ...help

Comment: Dude, you already posted this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preload the image to know the height, otherwise you'll never get the correct height for each image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".one").each(function(){
    var wrap = $(this),
    wrapH = wrap.outerHeight(),
    img = wrap.find('img'),
    image = new Image(),
    imgH = 0,
    padTop = 0;

    image.onload = function () {
        imgH = img.outerHeight();
        padTop = ( wrapH - ( imgH ) )/2;
        if ( padTop > 0 ){
             img.css("margin-top", padTop + "px");
        }
    }

    image.src = img.attr('src');

  });
});
```

Also, please note the use of $(this) inside the "each" method context to get the current '.one' element in every "each" step, and also jQuery's find method to locate the img tag that is child of the specified element. Using $('.one') and $('img') will always select every '.one' and 'img' element in the document.

Comment: Perfect, you answer my question. I realy need to learn moe about jquery! thx

Comment: last question : what is the last code line for? ("image.src = img.attr('src');")

Comment: image.src = img.attr('src') sets the src attribute of the javascript Image class instance with the src attribute of the image tag. When this attribute is set, the image starts loading and as soon as it is loaded it triggers the onload event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing
`var imgH = $("img").outerHeight();` to 
`var imgH = $(".one img").outerHeight();`

Also change
 `$("img").css("margin-top", padTop + "px");` to
 `$(".one img").css("margin-top", padTop + "px");`

Comment: Great, this solves one of my ploblems, it only aplies to the right images but it still gives the same margin-top to both images...